# django-filer не получатся создать модель

Tags: python, django

При makemigrations выдается ошибка

```
    super(FilerFileField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Вот модель:

```
from django.db import models
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField 

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cover = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True, related_name="book_covers")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно обязательно прописать параметр on_delete, что будет происходить при удалении объекта картинки. Тут будет ставиться Null

```
cover = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True, related_name="book_covers", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!